# MATLAB candle chart handle

Tags: matlab, candlestick-chart

When I use

```
>> load disney;
>> hcndl = candle(dis('3/31/98::4/30/98'))

hcndl =

  176.0044
  178.0032
  177.0031
```

How can I use this handle to change the background color of the chart.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for the set function. Set function accepts the handle of the figure and allows you to change the properties of the figure.

```
handle  = candle(dis('3/31/98::4/30/98'));
set(handle,'BackgroundColor','blue');
```

Comment: I get this result???? Error using ==> set
There is no 'BackgroundColor' property in the 'lineseries' class.

Comment: I'm sorry then. You probably has to ask for the parent handle as Jonas suggests. I didn't realize it returns the handle to lineseries.

Answer (score 1):

You want to modify the color of the axes. `candle` gives you handles to lines, whose parent are the axes you'd like to modify.

```
load disney;
hcndl = candle(dis('3/31/98::4/30/98'));

%# find handle to axes using the first of the three handles
%# note that you could have used any of the three
axH = get(hcndl(1),'Parent');

%# modify axes
set(axH,'Color','k') %# black color
```